# Handle Connection Error when calling seam remote function in javascript

Tags: javascript, seam, seam2

I use seam 2 with javscript remote object and it works fine but I wonder how to handle if the server is unavaible. Currently it display an 503 error on a javascript popup, which is quite awful.

i tried

```
try {
    var remoteObject= Seam.Component.getInstance("remoteObject");
    if(remoteObject){
        sessionChecker.remoteFunction(parameter, functionCallBack);
    }else{
        alert('error');
    }
} catch(err) {
    alert('error');
}
```

but without success -> still the annoying default popup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see [this link](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBSEAM-4026?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3aall-tabpanel).

Either patch file attached in issue or use at least Seam 2.2.2.

Comment: we are using Seam 2.2.2 ... We will move to 2.3 apparently. thanks for the link :)